# как из массива вытащить данные?

Tags: php

Задача нужно вывести все входящие сообщения (речь идет об API telegram..)

Я сделал запрос:

```
 $v_d = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot155786728:AAHmcineLW6WFxBs6XuH0liWYuM0W1lqqKQ/getUpdates");
    $value = json_decode($v_d, TRUE);
    var_dump($value)."<br/>";
```

Вышел такой ответ:

```
array(2) { ["ok"]=> bool(true) ["result"]=> array(8) { [0]=> array(2) { ["update_id"]=> int(125804848) ["message"]=> array(5) { ["message_id"]=> int(28) ["from"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(178282468) ["first_name"]=> string(5) "Ismar" ["last_name"]=> string(10) "Suleymanov" } ["chat"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(178282468) ["first_name"]=> string(5) "Ismar" ["last_name"]=> string(10) "Suleymanov" ["type"]=> string(7) "private" } ["date"]=> int(1447495291) ["text"]=> string(6) "**asdasd**" } }
```

Как из этого массива вытащить только текст? (текст помечен). Пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (  $value["result"] as $msg ){
  echo $msg["text"];
}
```

Comment: $value["result"][0]["message"]["text"] - этот код выводит только одно сообщение, а надо так чтобы вывелись все

Comment: @Ismar исправил

Comment: foreach (  $value["result"] as $msg ){
    echo $msg["message"]["text"]."<br/>";
}   Спасибо огромное!